# Graceful exiting of a program in Python?

Tags: python

I have a script that runs as a

```
while True:
  doStuff()
```

What is the best way to communicate with this script if I need to stop it but I don't want to kill it if it is in the middle of an operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to rewrite the script so it doesn't use `while True:`.

Sadly, it's impossible to conjecture a good way to terminate this.

You could use the Linux signals.

You could use a timer and stop after a while.

You could have `dostuff` return a value and stop if the value is `False`.

You could check for a local file and stop if the file exists.

You could check an FTP site for a remote file and stop of the file exists.

You could check an HTTP web page for information that indicates if your loop should stop or not stop.

You could use OS-specific things like semaphores or shared memory.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, definitely some good ideas there I wasn't thinking about.

Answer (score 9):

And I'm assuming you mean killing from outside the python script.

The way I've found easiest is

```
@atexit.register
def cleanup()
  sys.unlink("myfile.%d" % os.getpid() )

f = open("myfile.%d" % os.getpid(), "w" )
f.write("Nothing")
f.close()
while os.path.exists("myfile.%d" % os.getpid() ):
  doSomething()
```

Then to terminate the script just remove the myfile.xxx and the application should quit for you. You can use this even with multiple instances of the same script running at once if you only need to shut one down. And it tries to clean up after itself....

Answer (score 5):

I think the most elegant would be:

```
keep_running = true
while keep_running:
    dostufF()
```

and then `dostuff()` can set `keep_running = false` whenever in no longer wants to keep running, then the while loop ends, and everything cleans up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If that's a console aplication and exiting by pressing Ctrl+C is ok, could that solve your problem?

```
try:
  while True:
    doStuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  doOtherStuff()
```

I guess the problem with that approach is that you wouldn't have any control exactly when and where in doStuff the execution is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I've implemented such a thing. It catches `Ctrl+C` (or keyboard interrupt). It uses my package [`snuff-utils`](https://github.com/egorgvo/utils#graceful-exit).

To install:

```sh
pip install snuff-utils
```

```py
from snuff_utils.graceful_exit import graceful_exit

while True:
    do_task_until_complete()
    if graceful_exit:
        do_stuff_before_exit()
        break
```

On `Ctrl+C` it will log:

```
An interrupt signal has been received. The signal will be processed according to the logic of the application.
```

The goal I was after is to exit program but only after finishing already running task.

**Be careful with multiprocessing/multithreading. It is not tested.**

Answer (score -1):

The signal module can trap signals and react accordingly?